# unable to call method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm trying to implement ZXing barcode scanner into my program. After getting the scanned result, I wanted to parse the result to a method named `getData()` which belong to another Java class.  No syntax error on IDE, but `mysql.getData(contents)` won't call the method no matter what.  Please advise.

If I put this code under `onCreate`, the whole program force closed:

```
package com.posQR.ip;

import com.posQR.ip.MySQL;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class PosQRActivity extends Activity{
MySQL mysql;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);    
    mysql.getData("productID");
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(scanListener);

}

public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    if (requestCode == 0) {
    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
    try {
        String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), contents + "from main", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        mysql.getData(contents);
        String string = Double.toString(mysql.getPrice());
        textView.setText(string);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please scan on the product's QR Code.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
    // Handle cancel
    }

    }
    }

    private OnClickListener scanListener = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
    try{
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.zxing.client.android.SCAN");
    intent.putExtra("SCAN_MODE", "QR_CODE_MODE");
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "error opening scanner.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    }
    };
}
```

.

```
package com.posQR.ip;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ParseException;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MySQL{
double Price;
private Context localContext;

public void getData(String productID) {
InputStream is = null;
String result = "";

Toast.makeText(localContext.getApplicationContext(), productID, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("id",productID));
//http post
try{
 HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://dl.dropbox.com/u/11233767/mysqlRequest.php");
 httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
 HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
 HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
 is = entity.getContent();
 }catch(Exception e){
     Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection"+e.toString());
}
//convert response to string
try {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line = null;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line + "\n");
}
is.close();
result = sb.toString();
} catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
Toast.makeText(localContext.getApplicationContext(), "Error converting result.",    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//paring data

try{
  JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
  JSONObject json_data=null;
         json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(0);
         Price=json_data.getDouble("price");

  }
  catch(JSONException e1){
      Toast.makeText(localContext.getApplicationContext(), "No City Found" ,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  } catch (ParseException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
}
}

public double getPrice(){
return Price;
}

}
```

Comment: Anything in logcat? Have you tried using a debugger?

Comment: Looks like you are working on Android.  If so, please tag it accordingly.

Comment: Am I missing something, or didn't you even initialize your `mysql`-field? As the methods are not static in the class, you would need an object of the class.

Comment: MySQL mysql; <- is this not initialize? sorry very noob in programming here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many problems here, such as:

1. the `mysql` variable is null when you use it in `onCreate`, you must declare it.
2. The `localContext` object in MySql is never initialized, which will cause another `NullPointerException` when you call `getData()`. You should create a constructor that accepts a `Context` object for the MySql class, and use that constructor when you're fixing the first problem. Alternatively you could pass a Context object to `getData()`
3. the `getData()` method accesses the network in the main/UI thread, which will cause another Exception. Call this method in a different thread or spin off a new thread within the method itself. You may want to use an AsyncTask

Comment: hi, i understand about the first 2, but dont quite get it with the number 3. whats the problem exactly calling method from another class like that?

Comment: You are calling the getData method from the same thread, which is the main thread that takes care of the UI. Not only is this bad practice, but Android won't actually let you do it. Read this article about threading in Android: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/painless-threading.html